# Issue with TypeScript 2.0 @types - specificaly "angular" one

Tags: visual-studio, typescript2.0

Long story short, I'm trying to transition from TS 1.8 to 2.* version and one of the third party typings I use is for "angular". So now I reference them from npm @types repository and they seem to come already modified with second versions standards...

And I'm getting this issue:

[image]

Looks like neither Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code, and gulp compiler doesn't understand that reference with it's new attribute "types".

I have typescript@2.0.3 installed globally.

In tsconfig.json under compilerOptions property I have added:

```
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types/"],
    "types": [
      "angular",
...
    ]
```

But it does not solve the issue. Maybe someone knows solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by updating visual studio typescript version, you can get latest here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/07/11/announcing-typescript-2-0-beta/